# Load_Cycle_Cont increase quick / green hdd dead

Tags: 14.04, kernel, hard-drive, system, 14.10

an old bug is still there:
I use a normal hdd, and the Load_Cycle_Count increade very quick. Every few secounds 
go the hdd to the park position and is wake up again.

One hdd i lost because this bug. The problem is with ubuntu 14.04, 14.10, debian 5,6,7
(and other systems i think).

There are much articles in the internet about this, but no one solve it yet.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/969165

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem and also lost a hard drive a while back. To fix this, I set hdparm to prevent spindowns alltogether to prevent this problem. Here's how it can be done. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
echo "hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda" | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/power.d/90_hdparm
```

Now, make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/90_hdparm
```

Make a copy to sleep.d

```
sudo cp /etc/pm/power.d/90_hdparm /etc/pm/sleep.d
```

Finally, your laptop will switch to a powersave mode everytime you unplug the AC and go to battery power. To prevent this from changing hdparm settings, use gedit to edit the file /etc/hdparm.conf:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hdparm.conf
```

and copy/paste the following to the end of the file:

```
/dev/sda {
    apm = 254
    apm_battery = 254
}
```

Save the file in gedit and exit.

Reboot and check to verify the changes with the following command after you reboot:

```
sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda
```

source: [Making hdparm setting permanent](http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2012/07/making-hdparm-setting-permanent-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Also, make sure hdapsd is not running:

```
sudo service hdapsd stop
```

and uninstall thinkpad drivers if they are installed and not needed:

```
sudo apt-get purge tp-smapi-*
```

[Click here form more info on this issue and disk parking.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hard_Drive_Active_Protection_System)